# In SQL create yearly summary tables with sub-totals to date, for all of the options for a variable

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a data set like so:

```
FILE_NUMBER, DATE_RECEIVED, FILE_TYPE
```

FILE_TYPE has about 10 options.  And I hope to generate a summary table, that shows for each of the last four years (including this year):

```
YEAR, TOTAL_RECEIVED_TO_DATE, FILE_TYPE_1_TOTAL, FILE_TYPE_2_TOTAL, ....
2016, 3000, 126, 234, ....
2017, 3200, 123, 242, ....
2018, 3100, 234, 267, ....
```

I have tried several derived tables without any success.

Comment: Have you researched pivot?

Comment: @dfundako I am researching that now and trying it but it seems to be beyond my skill set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select year(DATE_RECEIVED), count(*) as total,
       sum(case when FILE_TYPE = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as file_type_1,
       sum(case when FILE_TYPE = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as file_type_2,
       . . .,
       sum(case when FILE_TYPE = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as file_type_10
from x
group by year(DATE_RECEIVED)
```